# ImportError: No module named 'scipy._lib'

Tags: linux, python, raspberry-pi

I am want to burn my python code on raspberry pi for my project. My code uses KNN function which requires sklearn library which in turn requires scipy library that I installed by the following methods:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy

pip install python-scipy
```

etc. Also, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it. But even after these methods I keep on getting the following same error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4363d2be0702> in <module>
----> 1 import scipy

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.py in <module>
    108 
    109     from scipy.version import version as __version__
--> 110     from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion as _NumpyVersion
    111     if _NumpyVersion(__numpy_version__) < '1.8.2':
    112         import warnings

ImportError: No module named 'scipy._lib'
```

Comment: Have you already tried using `pip install scipy` (instead of python-scipy)?

Answer (score 1):

As [Niayesh Isky](https://superuser.com/users/684722/niayesh-isky) pointed out the packagename of SciPy is not `python-scipy` it is `scipy` so pls try:

```
pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the python file with `sudo` . I had faced a similar issue with `scapy library` . Later the import error was not observed when I ran my py file using `sudo`.

Comment: I didn't exactly get what are you suggesting. I have tried installing scipy using sudo, it gave me the same error as above.

Comment: Sorry , I thought u were facing this issue when executing py file in which you are importing script .   Is the Path added properly ??  I meant path in environment variables